# Does "subject to review" mean there is a possibility of review or that it is guaranteed?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

Paypal said, *"All transfers are subject to review and could be delayed or stopped if we identify an issue."*

I'm a native English speaker, but I don't know if "subject to review" means all transfers **are** reviewed, or if it means all transfers are under the **possibility** of a review?

I assume Paypal doesn't manually check each transaction, and I don't care if they do or not, but I'm curious about what the phrase literally means, regardless of Paypal's potential misuse.

I guess "subject" here is being used in the same way a peasant is a 'subject' of a feudal lord, i.e. the transaction is under the lordship/authority of reviewers?

*Note: I don't care what Paypal actually does. Answers of Paypal's procedures are likely offtopic to the site and probably uninteresting to me. I'm curious about the words themselves, regardless of who spoke them.*

Comment: ***subject** to X* means [*affected by or **possibly** affected by X.*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject%20to) But ***subjected** to X* is unambiguous - it was ***definitely** X'd*.

Comment: But if PayPal *does* actually review every transaction by some method or another, wouldn't that show how they *intend* the sentence to be read, or support an answer about the English itself? Although I agree that a discussion of PayPal itself is OT.

Comment: @WeatherVane: ***Subject to review*** doesn't inherently exclude the possibility that in practice they review *every* transaction. But it leaves it open (whereas ***subjected** to review* quite strongly implies every transaction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subject-to?q=subject+to+something) has this entry (my bolding)

> **subject to something**
> <sub>idiom</sub>
>
> ***likely*** to experience or suffer from something
> *The bay is subject to heavy fog in summer.*
>
> If an action or event is subject to something, it ***needs*** something to happen before it can take place
> *The agreement is still subject to approval by the League's 30 teams and the players.*

These are two different usages of the phrase. The first one **might** and the second one **must**, so it can't be determined from the OP's statement whether Paypal reviews *every* transaction or not.

But the overall meaning seems to be that PayPal does not guarantee that a transaction, once made, will be completed promptly, or at all.

Answer (score 2):

> "All transfers are subject to review and could be delayed or stopped
> if we identify an issue."

This means that Paypal *might* delay or stop the transfers if they choose to do a review.

You may also see the phrase "reserve the right to", as in:

**Paypal *reserves the right* to review all transfers and may also delay or stop them if issues are identified.**

or, simply, "may", sometimes with "at our option":

**We *may, at our option*, review any transfers and delay or stop them if issues are identified.**

These are all extremely close in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Since the context is Paypal, a [legal dictionary](https://thelawdictionary.org/subject-to/) is the place to go for the meaning. Unfortunately, it's ambiguous, but I think it's safe to say that any court would accept that Paypal has reserved the right to review transfers and to take appropriate action if the review should reveal an issue.

> 1. Conditional or dependent on something. 2. Being under domination as of a authority or government subject to the whims of the boss.3.
>    Exposed or open to undesirable or unfortunate criticism. 4. The
>    necessity of undergoing something. 5. Liable or prone to suffer
>    something

P.S. It looks as though that dictionary page may have been crowd-sourced, which is strange.

Comment: I don't think "subject to" has a technical meaning in law that is different from that of its ordinary use.

Comment: @BadZen: Inasmuch as this phrase appears in a Terms of Service document, the meaning isn't  necessarily governed by standard English usage.  Perhaps it would be better asked on the law forum, even if it should turn out to be the case that in contractual contexts its meaning cannot be precisely pinned down, as is the case in non-legal contexts.